# How can i return from recursive method and then continure the recursive method from the last returned point?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this two methods

```
private List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> str = MyGetDirectories(basePath);

            List<DirectoryInfo> l = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            l.Add(new DirectoryInfo(basePath));

            IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = str.Select(a => new DirectoryInfo(a));
            l.AddRange(dirs);

            return l;
        }
```

And

```
static int countDirectories = 0;
    private IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
            if (dirs.Length > 0)
                return dirs.Union(dirs);
            countDirectories = countDirectories + dirs.Length;
            _FileInformationWorker.ReportProgress(countDirectories,dirs);
            return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
```

And in a backgroundworker dowork this

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            MySubDirectories = GetDirectories(BasePath).ToArray();
        }
```

Instead waiting for the method MyGetDirectories to finish I want to update in the dowork event the variable MySubDirectories each time the variable dirs. change. In this case first time dirs Length is 36 so I make return and I see that MySubDirectories contain 36 items. The problem now is that the recursive in the method MyGetdirectories won't continue. I want it to continue so next time dirs length is above 0 for example next time it will be 3 then update MySubDirectories so now MySubDirectories will contain the new 3 items that are in dirs.

I don't want to stop the recursive I just want to keep updating the MySubDirectories in real time.

What I tried so far and did is in the method MyGetdirectories i'm also reporting the dirs variable:

```
_FileInformationWorker.ReportProgress(countDirectories, dirs);
```

Then in the progresschanged event did:

```
List<string[]> testing = new List<string[]>();
        private void _FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
            string[] test = (string[])e.UserState;
            if (test.Length > 0)
                testing.Add(test);
        }
```

But now i'm ending with a List of string[] arrays. And test is string[]
Is there any way to cast/convert the string[] to DirectoryInfo[] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782

```
// Hand-off through a BufferBlock<T>
private static BufferBlock<int> m_buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();

// Producer
private static void Producer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int item = Produce();
        m_buffer.Post(item);
    }
}

// Consumer
private static async Task Consumer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int item = await m_buffer.ReceiveAsync();
        Process(item);
    }
}

// Main
public static void Main()
{
    var p = Task.Factory.StartNew(Producer);
    var c = Consumer();
    Task.WaitAll(p,c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

test.Select(p => new DirectoryInfo(p)).ToArray();